# Custom listview with image in android

Tags: android

I am new in android and i want to do parsing through api and then load the data in the background and then displaying the data of image and text in custom listview, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this tuts there are parsing with image and text with row in listview.....

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: I had seen this link but the parsing is with the help of Dom parser and i need to do it with Sax parser please help

Comment: you have just change parse just googling and check sax parser in android

Comment: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example                 http://www.technotalkative.com/android-sax-parsing-example/

Comment: this i had seen the same but i want your source code with sax parser and display it in custom listview

Comment: you have to make some efforts this is not code repositery and try in github.com

Comment: actually i had done it but facing some problem will u help me ?

Answer (score -1):

The best thing to do is to create your own ListAdapter that will extend BaseAdapter. 
You'll need to create your custom layout for single element of the list.
Here is very good example how to do it: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: This i had seen but it uses Dom parser and i need to do it with the help of Sax parser please help